# JetBrains PyCharm 5.x Intellisense for method parameters

Tags: pycharm

When you write a method invocation in PyCharm, you get a brief overview of all the parameters on the method call (see screenshot below). However, if you leave this area empty, and come back to it, you don't get the same overview of parameters.

That leaves me with the following options:

- Re-type the parentheses (works, but feels unpolished)
- Use CTRL + SPACE (which gives a vertical auto-completion list of more than just parameters)
- Use `COMMAND + F1` (which only reports missing mandatory parameters)

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to get back to:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can I re-invoke the overview of method parameters, without having to re-type the parentheses? I feel like there should be a keyboard shortcut for this, but if it exists, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mac OS X

According to the [documentation for JetBrains PyCharm 5.0](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/viewing-method-parameter-information.html), you can use the `COMMAND + P` keyboard shortcut to invoke the "*Parameter Info*" function. This achieves the desired effect.

## Windows

On Windows, you can press **SHIFT** twice to invoke "Search Everywhere" and search for the "Parameter Info" command. The default keyboard shortcut appears to be **CTRL + SHIFT + SPACE**.

[image]